# Creating Custom AJAX Client Control inside another AJAX Client Control and passing first one as ref

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I want to pass reference of first created object (ref to initialized object ) to another and call the Print method.

aspx:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager01">
     <scripts>                  
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="object.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="firstobj.js" />
     </scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>


 <script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad(sender, args) {                   
       $create(CustomControls.FirstObj, { text: 'Some Text'}, null, null, $get('Button1'));

    }    

 </script>

 <button type="button" id="Button1"></button>&nbsp;
```

firstobj.js:

```
Type.registerNamespace("CustomControls");

// Constructor
CustomControls.FirstObj = function(element) {

    CustomControls.FirstObj.initializeBase(this, [element]);
    this._clickDelegate = null;

}
CustomControls.FirstObj.prototype = {

    // text property accessors.
    get_text: function() {
        return this.get_element().innerHTML;
    },
    set_text: function(value) {
        this.get_element().innerHTML = value;
    },

    // Bind and unbind to click event.
    add_click: function(handler) {
        this.get_events().addHandler('click', handler);
    },
    remove_click: function(handler) {
        this.get_events().removeHandler('click', handler);
    },



    // Release resources before control is disposed.
    dispose: function() {

        var element = this.get_element();

        if (this._clickDelegate) {
            Sys.UI.DomEvent.removeHandler(element, 'click', this._clickDelegate);
            delete this._clickDelegate;
        }


        CustomControls.FirstObj.callBaseMethod(this, 'dispose');
    },

    initialize: function() {
        debugger;

        var element = this.get_element();

        //if (!element.tabIndex) element.tabIndex = 0;

        if (this._clickDelegate === null) {
            this._clickDelegate = Function.createDelegate(this, this._clickHandler);
        }
        Sys.UI.DomEvent.addHandler(element, 'click', this._clickDelegate);


        CustomControls.FirstObj.callBaseMethod(this, 'initialize');

    },
    _clickHandler: function(event) {
        debugger;      
        $create(CustomControls.Newobj, null, null, null, document);
    },
    _Print: function() {
        alert("print");
    },


}
CustomControls.FirstObj.registerClass('CustomControls.FirstObj', Sys.UI.Control);
if (typeof (Sys) !== 'undefined') Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
```

object.js:

```
Type.registerNamespace("CustomControls");

// Constructor
CustomControls.Newobj = function(element) {

CustomControls.Newobj.initializeBase(this, [element]);


}
CustomControls.Newobj.prototype = {              

    // Release resources before control is disposed.
    dispose: function() {    

        CustomControls.Newobj.callBaseMethod(this, 'dispose');
    },

    initialize: function() {
        debugger;
       //CALL PRINT OF FIRSTOBJ    

        CustomControls.Newobj.callBaseMethod(this, 'initialize');

    },

}
CustomControls.Newobj.registerClass('CustomControls.Newobj', Sys.UI.Control);

if (typeof (Sys) !== 'undefined') Sys.Application.notifyScriptLoaded();
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw your post when I was looking for the same thing.  It looks like the Microsoft script added a load event that fires after all the scripts have been loaded and objects have been created and can start referencing each other.

Take a look at
http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/ClientReference/Sys/ApplicationClass/SysApplicationLoadEvent.aspx